# Is there an efficient way of calling the same method on all objects of type T?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, methods, repeat

Let's say I have 10 TextBoxes and all of them have different values but they are all TextBoxes. And, I have a method `CheckInputValue(Textbox tb)`. Now, on the click of a button, I would like the method to check all textboxes and determine if the value is allowed.

But I don't want to do this:

```
        void DoWork()
    {
        CheckInputValue(t1);
        CheckInputValue(t2);
        CheckInputValue(t3);
        CheckInputValue(t4);
        ...
        CheckInputValue(tx);

    }
```

**PLEASE NOTE: The above is just an example.**

I have a complex method that needs to be executed on several controls of the same type and I have about 25 controls. Is there are a more elegant way of doing this?
Thank you.

Comment: I think you shouldn't validate data inside the controls. You should validate the data that in your view model. In that case, you can add an attribute (i.e. [Validate]) to properties of your view model and when you'll need you can gather all the properties that have that attribute and validate the values.

Comment: Is it difficult to create a set of all of the controls that you want to evaluate? That would seem to be the hard part.

Comment: Are the controls in some collection implementing `IEnumerable<T>`?

Comment: This is an interesting question. I (but I'm a beginner as well) would think that you have to do that writing at some point or another, and it just depends on what part you want to repeat. You could e.g. add all the TextBoxes you want to use `CheckInputValue` on to a `List` (or some `IEnumerable<TextBox>`) and then use `foreach`. That would have the (small) advantage that you don't have to add *every* TextBox, whereas a method as the one you seem to search would execute on *all* TextBoxes, and there might be some you don't want to be used.

Comment: @IvanZub This was just an example. I need to call a method on several controls and I felt that it wasn't very elegant to call the method n number of times like Method(i1), Method (i2), Method(in).

Comment: @Jodrell Unfortunately NO! They're all children in several StackPanels to form a specific layout :(

Comment: @KeithPayne I believe so...It will be a bit difficult :(

Comment: @NavikGoswami check my answer. Maybe you can simplify it a little bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that :

```
List<TextBox> tbxList = new List<TextBox>()
{
    t1,
    t2,
    t3,
    t4
};

foreach (Textbox tbx in tbxList)
{
    CheckInputValue(tbx);
}
```

Comment: Sorry if I'm being a a bit too demanding but is there an even more elegant way of adding the controls into the list something like i++ because all my controls are named as i1, i2, i3....ix :S

Comment: Or will I have to manually write them like i1, i2....ix ? P.S There are a lot of those controls!

Comment: I understand that I will have to increment the number everytime to the base name of the control, but I can't figure out how can I add that between the `List<TextBox> tbxList = new List<TextBox>()
{` and `};` Sorry :S

Comment: But I'm satisfied with your answer and will mark it as such. Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If you have all `t`'s in a list, you could use [`List<T>.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
listWithT.ForEach(CheckInputValue);
```

Or loop over them with a regular `foreach`:

```
foreach (T t in list)
{
    CheckInputValue(t);
}
```

Or create an inline array:

```
foreach (T t in new T[] { t1, t2, t3 })
{
    CheckInputValue(t);
}
```

If not, there is no easy way to do so.

Comment: frankly, if you had them in a list, you could just `foreach` - it would be simpler and more efficient ;p But it would work

Comment: I like the idea of creating an inline array using foreach :) But as I have a lot of control, will I have to manually specify the names of the controls? I'm asking this because - all my controls are appropriately named like i1, i2, i3...ix

Comment: @NavikGoswami: There is, like Benji answered, but such code is asking for problems. I strongly advise not to use that!

Comment: @Navik "Appropriately" is not quite...ehh, appropriate... Your controls should have more descriptive names unless they are part of an actual list, in which case you should probably be managing them dynamically by adding/removing them from the form as they're needed. (In which case you'll already have them in a list).

Comment: @ChristopherPfohl: Good point made. That's exactly what it is about!

Comment: @PatrickHofman I finally ended up manually adding them to the List<T> :) and I agree they're not "appropriately" named. It's just  that's how they are supposed to be named in my application as they are children of a parent container which will only be accessed once :)

Comment: @PatrickHofman Btw, I tried the `ListwithT.foreach` but it didn't let me use the `Method()` saying the method doesn't take 0 arguments :|

Answer (score 1):

> Sorry if I'm being a a bit too demanding but is there an even more
>   elegant way of adding the controls into the list something like i++
>   because all my controls are named as i1, i2, i3....ix :S

You can do that (but it's dirty) :

```
int n_tbx = 5;
List<TextBox> tbxList = new List<TextBox>();

for (int i = 0; i < n_tbx; i++)
{
    //Where "this" is your mainframe
    tbxList.Add(this.Controls.Find("t"+i, true).FirstOrDefault() as TextBox);
}

foreach (Textbox tbx in tbxList)
{
    CheckInputValue(tbx);
}
```

Comment: Yes you're right. I think I'd better add them manually to the list. and I don't think you can use `this.Controls` in a Windows Phone Application.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have an idea about how you can make it little bit easier and in more MVVM way. It's simplified - no property changing reporting, typing in attribute and stuff.. Just for you to get the idea.
So the main idea is that you can mark all the properties that should be validated with some kind of attribute (in that case ValidateAttribute) and using single Validate method you can gather all the properties and validate it in one place.

```
class SampleViewModel
{
    [Validate]
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }

    [Validate]
    public string AnotherProperty { get; set; }

    public void Validate()
    {
        foreach (var propertyInfo in GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).Where(p => p.IsDefined(typeof(ValidateAttribute), true)))
        {
            var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(this, null);
            Validate(value as string);
        }
    }

    private void Validate(string value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            // do something with the invalid input, i.e. throw the exception
        }
    }
}

class ValidateAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to build on the previous answer and let you have the code do the work for you, so you can call a single method and get the results you want:

You can inherit from textbox and add in some functionality that will have all of he characteristics of textbox but also will add itself to a single list that keeps track of all of these object:

```
 public class CustomTextBox :TextBox
{
    private static List<CustomTextBox> CustomTextBoxList = new List<CustomTextBox>();

    public static async void ValidateAll()
    {
        foreach (CustomTextBox MyCustomTextBox in CustomTextBoxList)
        {
            ****PERFORM VALIDATION****
        }
    }

    public CustomTextBox ()
    {
        CustomTextBoxList.Add(this);
    }

    ~CustomTextBox()
    {
        CustomTextBoxList.Remove(this);
    }
}
```

It's very easy to add these to your XAML page (sorry I'm not sure how to put XAML in these answer):

```
Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
  StackPanel
     local:CustomTextBox Text="A" Width="150" Margin="10"/
     local:CustomTextBox Text="B" Width="150" Margin="10"/
     local:CustomTextBox Text="C" Width="150" Margin="10"/
     local:CustomTextBox Text="D" Width="150" Margin="10"/
     local:CustomTextBox Text="E" Width="150" Margin="10"/
     Button Content="Validate TextBoxes!" Click="Button_Click"/
  /StackPanel
/Grid
```

When you click the button, it calls a single function that will perform validation on all of them at the same time:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   CustomTextBox.ValidateAll();
}
```